# SQL/C# - Designing a table for products that have more than 50 features(true/false)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm having an issue with the design of a new table which will hold the features of our products. At first I hard-coded the features into columns like this:

```
ProductExtrasID | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature.. 50
1                 true         true         false
2                 false        true         false
```

.. and so on.. and I used ProductExtrasID as a foreign key to the products table and only display the features that were 'True'.

Now I was asked that the Features should be done dynamically so that each admin of the site could add a new Feature.

What I thought of doing so far was this

```
ProductExtrasID |ProductID | Feature Description   | FeatureActive
    1                20        feature1 description      false
    2                20        feature2 description      true
    3                30        feature1 description      true
   ...
```

Then show the features of each product ID where FeatureActive is true.

Is this a good approach to accomplish what I want or can it be done better?

Thank you

Comment: I think you need create table [Features], and for 2nd table create foreign key for that table instead adding [feature description]. And as Damien says- you don't need FeatureActive in that case.

Comment: Why don't you create a vertical table contains feature and product properties instead of writing numerous features to horizontally ?

Comment: If all features are simply on/off, I'd have thought a two-column table (ProductID, FeatureID) would be all that's required. The *presence* of a row means "true" and the *absence* of a row implies false. You don't want to have repeated descriptions for the features so store those once elsewhere.

Comment: @Emre - It's many-to-many connection: few products can have few features.

Comment: @Anamnian I think creating a seperate table like Features can help to achieve desired output. So doing that, ProductExtras table contains ProductId, FeatureId, FeatureActive. It is many2many relation and horizontal structure, adding new feature does not affect that table. Aren't we say the same solution? (:

Comment: @Emre Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

Create a table for all features:

```
ID  |  Feature Description
1     feature1 description
2     feature2 description
3     feature1 description
```

And then use it in table ProductsFeatures:

```
ProductExtrasID |ProductID | FeatureID
    1                20        1      
    2                20        2      
    3                30        1
```

And if You need show something like this:

```
Product20: 
    feature1: true,
    feature2: true,
    feature10: false.
(and not show another 47 features)
```

You need to create additional table ProductTypesFeatures:

```
ProductTypeID |FeatureID
1                1      
1                2 
1                10
2                1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a separate Product table and Feature Table. 
You can then link the two tables using a linking table.

You could call the linking table something like "ProductFeatureLink". and it should look similar to the below:

```
ProductExtrasID|FeatureID|FeatureActive

1              |1        |false   
1              |2        |true
2              |1        |true
```

The separate feature table will allow the creation/deletion of features and will allow you to easily link it up in a many to many scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good approach to accomplish what I want or can it be done
>   better?

Yes it can be better.

You should ask yourself whether it is meaningful to separate a product from its features. Ask yourself: can two different products have the same product features? Can two different product have feature "Colour is Green", "Size XL" "LCD Touch Screen" Is a feature meaningful if there isn't a Product with this feature? Can it be that a certain feature does not exist yet, but it might exist in the future ("Solar powered"), Can it be that a feature is not used anymore by any of your products ("Steam Powered")

I think you want to be able to add a new feature to your database without having to add a column to one of your tables. You want to be able to change one or more properties of a Feature, like the description, without having to change the structure of your database.

Using your current layout with Booleans won't allow adding a new feature: inflexible. The feature "Steam Powered" has a false value for all of your products: waste of space and processing power, Your features can't have any properties.

These problems would be solved if you implemented a many-to-many relation between the Products and the features: Every Product has zero or more features; Every feature is used/owned by zero  or more Products:

```
class Product
{
     public int ProductId {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public DateTime IntroductionDate {get; set;}
     ...

     // every Product has zero or more features
     // many-to-many using a junction table
}
class Feature
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    ...
    // every feature is had by zero or more products
    // many-to-many using a junction table
}
```

The junction table:

```
public class ProductsFeatures
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}   // Foreign key to Products
    public int FeatureId {get; set;}   // Foreign key to Features
}
```

To give Product P1 a feature F1, just add a row (P1, F1) to ProductsFeatures.

If product P2 has the feature: F2: "Black and White screen", and you want to change it to feature F3: "Colour screen", just remove ProductsFeature (P2, F2) and add (P2, F3). All other Products that had a Black and White Screen, will still have the black and white screen.

If you want the change the feature text for all products that have "Black and White screen" int "B&W screen", all you have to do is change the description of F2, and all products have the updated description.

If you want to delete product P1, all you do is delete all (P1, ...) from ProductsFeatures before deleting P1. Your database will warn you if you try to delete P1 while there are still features referring to P1